# Problems with json file2

Tags: python, json

Suppose there is a python variable named myVar containing a set of JSON elements in String format.

```
myVar = '{"name": "Bob", "languages": ["English", "French"]}'
```

Write a program to count the number of JSON objects in this variable.

```
 import json
 myVar = '{"name": "Bob", "languages": ["English", "French"]}'
```

expected result=2

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for the solution to a homework problem.

Comment: @MattDMo even though it is not its is a forum where people should have the right to ask simple questions like this.

Comment: Why do you expect `2`? I only see one `json` object (which contains some strings and an array)

Comment: @Flow, no, SO is *not* a forum. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions get *specific* answers. Questions like "*Please write this code for me*" are off-topic. This question is also a duplicate of hundreds of other questions on this site. Googling `python convert string to json` will give you the answer.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for this information did not know and I will make sure to keep the standard of stack  overflow.

Comment: @Flow for reference, definitely check out the [help] and the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq). There's a ton of good stuff there.

Comment: @MattDMo will do.

Answer (score 1):

using `json.loads` we can convert a string to the json type.and the using `len` gives us how many keys we have.

```py
import json
myVar = '{"name": "Bob", "languages": ["English", "French"]}'
jsonify_string = json.loads(myVar)
print(len(jsonify_string))
```

Comment: Don't use the names of [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) like `dict` as variable names. It shadows the built-in and leads to problems later.